# How I access my Facebook account that already opened using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

Suppose that my Facebook account is open now in browser, how to access to the same account directly (without email password) and to publish a post for ex using selenium?
Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

### Execution

Assuming you are using a chrome driver, this can be done by **importing your chrome user data**. Find the file that contains your user data with this format:

```
C:/Users/XXXUSERXXX/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data
```

Use the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

userdatadir = 'C:/Users/XXXUSERXXX/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data'
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={userdatadir}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)

driver.get("https://facebook.com")
```

As long as you have signed into Facebook under your current chrome browser, then it should automatically log you in without having to enter your username or password. One thing to note, you can only have **one chrome instance open at once** if you are importing your chrome user data.

Comment: i use linux where i find the path C:/Users/XXXUSERXXX/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data'?

Comment: @Azaiter Here is a helpful guide I found for whatever platform you need to find Chrome User Data on: https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/amp/

Comment: Can I do a get or post request  on the same webdriver that currently opens Facebook?